# Electrical wires identical

Tags: electrical, wiring, washing-machine, cord-and-plug

[image]

I’m trying to replace a plug on a washer cord. I’m having a hard time identifying neutral and positive even using the 6 items in the electric code 400.22 that is suppose to distinguish the two.

In answer to the questions asked:

The wires are separated in the cord, however the only one with insulated covering is the ground wire in the middle, on the pic I left a little of the green there so you could see it.

There is know distinguishing differences in the two wires.

I will take an post a better picture ASAP.

This is for a Kenmore Elite Automatic Washer, Top Loading.  The model is 110.24942301.

Thanks everyone.  Hopefully this posts this time[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you provide us with clearer photos of the cable, especially the writing on it?

Comment: What is the manufacturer/model # of the washing machine?

Comment: Does one side of the cable have ribbing and the other smooth?

Comment: You can just see that each wire is individually insulated.  You need to remove the outer jacket insulation while keeping the individual wire insulation intact.  Then you'll see the wire colors.

Comment: I agree with Harper if the wires rant color coded there should be a rib on 1 side. I would look inside the washer at the connections for hot and neutral markings.

Answer (score 1):

Wow they think those cords are made of gold at 46/47 bucks , here is a utube link on replacing the cord. I hope it works because I am having trouble with high speed today it started but I lost my connection.
https://youtu.be/Qn678UVUd5Q
Got it to run, pull the plastic end caps on the control panel, unscrew the screw at the bottom each end and flip up the control panel you can see the green ground white neutral and black wires on the Molex plug trace them back on the cord black to gold or black screw on the new plug, white to the silver and green to ground. That should do it.

Answer (score -1):

generally on a three wire stet up, the left and right wire are your HOT wires, The middle Ground acts as a neutral wire. on a 4 wire set up, you will have a designated neutral wire and a designated ground. A three wire set up is a little different. you will only have one wire (middle wire) acting as a ground as well as a neutral. there will be a "body" ground (green) screw that must be in place. This is usually installed by the factory. Sometimes they get removed by accident.. This factory ground wire is a safety device.

Comment: Ground is green NOT neutral , the outside wires 1 would be hot, and 1would be neutral. Unless this was a 240v device and the green wire would still be ground not neutral.